# How do I make VS Code parse Qt object names from .ui file?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, qt5

I'm looking for a way to make Visual Studio Code recognize object names from QtCreator's form (`.ui`) file. I really don't like to use QtCreator as a code editor, and I want to use it only for designing windows, which requires the `.ui` file. The problem is that QtCreator parses the object names from the `.ui` XML file to give code suggestions, even when the objects are not defined in an actual `.hpp` or `.cpp` file. VSCode does not do this, and shows a lot of errors in the code and does not suggest object/function/method names. I don't seem to find a way to get this functionality in VSCode. Is there a plugin or something similar that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit of researching. There is a VS Code extension called [Qt Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tonka3000.qtvsctools) that parses object names from the `.ui` file and shows code suggestions for those objects for seamless Qt development.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to deal with this problem is to turn the `.ui` file into a `.cpp` file, and point to it in an include statement at the top of your main code.

To do the conversion, use the 'UIC'.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html

The only problem is that you'll have to do this conversion every time you make a change to the `.ui` file.

Comment: Actually I've used this approach to make it work but it becomes a bit of a hassle converting the `ui` file into a header and cpp file agin and again. Thanks for the help though, I guess this is the only way out